# Crontab doesn't respect specified timezone (CRON_TZ or TZ)

Tags: 18.04, cron

I noticed that my script is probably running in a wrong time (UTC maybe?).
But I've added `CRON_TZ` into the `crontab`.

**EDIT**

---

It's **Ubuntu 18.04, DigitalOcean.com droplet** which was created from `snapshot`.

---

I've checked syntax and it is correct I think. Do you know where could be the problem?

```
CRON_TZ='Europe/Prague'
53 12 * * * touch /home/futilestudio/feedproject/cronsupervisor/scripts/touch0.txt
```

The script should be executed **12:53** Slovakia/Czech Republic time (in 24 hour format) but it wasn't - it haven't created a `touch0.txt`. If I execute it manually it works.

**CONFIRMED**

I tried to put there a command in UTC and it created a file (SK/CZ is 13:24 but UTC is 11:24 right now)

```
24 11 * * * touch /home/futilestudio/feedproject/cronsupervisor/scripts/touch0.txt
```

**EDIT**

It's 14:20 Prague time and I've set two jobs:

```
21 12 * * * TZ=Europe/Prague touch /home/futilestudio/feedproject/cronsupervisor/scripts/touch0.txt
21 14 * * * TZ=Europe/Prague touch /home/futilestudio/feedproject/cronsupervisor/scripts/touch1.txt
```

and removed touch0.txt from the directory.

14:21 - created `/home/futilestudio/feedproject/cronsupervisor/scripts/touch0.txt`

Comment: All the example I see do not have quotes around the place. 2 examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289751/cron-job-in-a-different-timezone and https://serverfault.com/questions/848829/how-to-use-timezone-with-cron-tab

Comment: @Rinzwind I tried it with and without too. The same problem. Now I tried to set 6 12 * * *  and 6 14 * * * and the first one was created which means it uses UTC...

Comment: AH!  Putting TZ=UTC in the crontab file only sets it for the cron jobs, not for cron itself. **It doesn't affect the timing of the job execution. **

Comment: @Rinzwind I tried. You can see it in EDIT at the bottom of the question.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/266302/15811 The top part is what you need

Comment: @Rinzwind Wow thanks, I thought it would be more straightforward.

Comment: @Rinzwind There was an even better way for my case but not for all cases. I just changed the server timezone. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Comment: Gratz on getting there :D Feel free to dupe your question if there is one, remove it or make an answer ;-)

Comment: Can you confirm what time your server is using, is it using UTC? `date` to see time/date `timedatectl` to see more details.

Comment: @Jeff I've solved it changing server timezone. As Rinzwind mentioned, CRON_TZ  is not cron timezone but rather script timezone.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting both CRON_TZ and TZ?

SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=me

CRON_TZ='Europe/Prague'

TZ='Europe/Prague'

53 12 * * * touch /home/futilestudio/feedproject/cronsupervisor/scripts/touch0.txt