# crontab with per-user timezones

Tags: cron, timezone

Following up on [How do you set the timezone for crontab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54364/), where CentOS 7 distro with cronie 1.4 has `CRON_TZ` environment variable, but Ubuntu 20.04 LTS'  `crontab(5)` manpage still doesn't have `CRON_TZ`. It says:

*"It currently does not support per-user timezones."*

I need to setup cron job on a remote server (in Europe, shared, not mine), which has different daylight saving time schedule than America.