# cronjob not runnig after hours are specified?

Tags: command-line, cron, python3

I was testing cronjobs for one of my projects. For that I made a simple telegram bot that sends me a message every minute.

The code is the following:

```py
import requests
from datetime import datetime
Token = "Token here"
OWNER_ID = Id here


def send():

    send_text="Message sent at : "+str(datetime.now())
    telegram_send = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{Token}/sendmessage?chat_id={OWNER_ID}&text={send_text}"
    requests.get(telegram_send)
    print("sent at : " , datetime.now())


send()
```

and my cronjob command was:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/anish/cowin/tester.py >> ~/cron.log 2>&1
```

The bot sent me a message every minute and the log files also recorded it:

```
sent at :  2021-05-26 14:37:02.681277
sent at :  2021-05-26 14:38:02.444642
sent at :  2021-05-26 14:39:02.189234
sent at :  2021-05-26 14:40:01.932228
sent at :  2021-05-26 14:41:02.695751
```

And this is what I received in the bot as expected:

[image: bot messages]

But when I changed the cronjob command to execute the command between 2pm and 6pm, the program execution stopped.

The new command I entered is:

```
* 14-18 * * *  /usr/bin/python3 /home/anish/cowin/tester.py >> ~/cron.log 2>&1
```

Can someone help me out with this problem or point out any error in my code?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is maybe cron's timezone is different from that of your user/locale. See somewhat related [How do you set the timezone for crontab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54364/how-do-you-set-the-timezone-for-crontab)

Comment: Didn't help still facing the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the cron services didn't detected the change in my systems timezone .

I got the issue solved by simply restarting cron services
`sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart`