# Why Cronjobs Run According to UTC Time?

Tags: command-line, cron, time, timezone

I am in Singapore and the server (Ubuntu 22.04 EC2 instance) is set according to the my local timezone (UTC+8H), at least so the `date` command tells me.

```
$ date
Wed Sep 20 09:07:42 +08 2023
```

Is this a conclusive proof that my timezone setting is local? Unfortunately, my `@daily` cronjobs run everyday at 8 am local time, which suggests somehow the cron daemon is following UTC time. Is there a separate timezone setting for the cron daemon other than what I am seeing in the terminal? This is my cron command.

```
@daily cd tensorflow_clustering/ && bash run_index.sh >> run.log
```

According to the comment,

```
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Wed 2023-09-20 10:03:11 +08
           Universal time: Wed 2023-09-20 02:03:11 UTC
                 RTC time: Wed 2023-09-20 02:03:10
                Time zone: Asia/Singapore (+08, +0800)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `@daily` with `0 0 * * *`? They are equivalent. Your problem is unusual. I have tried both of these in cron. I don't live in UTC.

Comment: A simple test is to add `* * * * * timedatectl > /tmp/date` to your `cron`, wait a minute and then check the file `/tmp/date`. Does that show a different output than when you run `timedatectl` manually?

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to change when the job runs:**

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/536489/1733436) for a system-wide solution that basically changes `/etc/timezone` which *cron* respects, according to [man 8 cron](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/cron.8.html#environment).

If you want to keep the system timezone and only change it for *cron*, you can try to put `TZ=Asia/Singapore` in `systemctl edit cron.service`, and then `systemctl restart cron`.

See [here](https://serverfault.com/a/848833/86431) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289751/cron-job-in-a-different-timezone#comment30804959_13290144) for possible per-job solutions.

**If you want to change the timezone the job runs with:**

Cronjobs respect the *TZ* environment variable provided by the *cron* daemon. The *cron* daemon allows setting environment variables in crontabs.

That means you can influence the timezone of cronjobs by setting *TZ* in your crontabs, e. g. in `crontab -e`:

```
@daily echo "I run with UTC"

# This timezone will apply to all cronjobs after this line
TZ=Asia/Singapore

@daily echo "I run with Singapore time"
```

Be aware that setting *TZ* in crontabs only affects the cronjobs, not *cron* itself, see above.

This defines the "local" timezone the job gets to use. It might be helpful for whatever the job does. Things like log message formats, the `date` command or the [Python datetime.timezone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects) object might use the "local" timezone.